# Add class to element when scrolling 100px above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class to each element (class abc) when it reaches 100px below the top of the viewport. However I cannot get the class added to each individual element. Rather it is adding the class to all divs. Any suggestions?

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.abc').offset().top - 100) {
      $(".abc").addClass("color");
    } else {
      $(".abc").removeClass("color");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 150px;
}

.abc {
  background-color: orange;
}

.color {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, this scrips is working! see https://jsfiddle.net/056vzoa2/

Comment: Oh I see, you need "color" in each .abc that is in the offset? you gonna have just one .abc.color each time?

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is correct for checking a single element, however to achieve this for a collection you need to loop over every element and evaluate their position individually. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    $('.abc').each(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('color', scrollTop >= $(this).offset().top - 100);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#header { height: 150px; }
.abc { background-color: orange; }
.color { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
<div class="abc">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper aliquam neque, id condimentum orci egestas ac. Maecenas ullamcorper semper finibus. Quisque vitae semper lorem, ut mattis mi. Maecenas ut porta enim. Duis tellus sem, tincidunt
  vitae turpis tristique, laoreet sodales nunc. Donec laoreet sollicitudin nibh, a porta risus elementum id. Vivamus et quam nec enim tincidunt tempus in sed ipsum. Quisque non arcu sem. Nulla eget massa ultricies, dignissim erat vel, tristique turpis.
  Pellentesque non maximus est, in feugiat nibh. Morbi enim elit, sodales ac leo eget, interdum imperdiet elit. Nunc dapibus scelerisque aliquet.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try something like this.

```
 $('.abc').each(function(){ //For each .abc
   if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top - 100) { //see if is in offset
      $('.abc').removeClass("color"); //remove all colors
      $(this).addClass("color"); //set the offset .abc with color
   } 
 })
```

Let me know if works... see this example. https://jsfiddle.net/056vzoa2/5/
Regards!

Comment: This works great. However I was also planning to use this in a div container with fixed position and this doesn't seem to work in this case. The container would be like this:

`#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}`

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, I'm just answering your question.